# Is it possible to modify language configuration on top of another extension in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to modify language configuration on top of another extension in VS code?
For example, I'm using extension [vscode-verilog-hdl-support](https://github.com/mshr-h/vscode-verilog-hdl-support) and its language configuration is written in JSON.

```
{
...
    "brackets": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["begin", "end"],
        ["case", "endcase"],
...
    ],
...
}
```

I want to add some more cases into `brackets` without cloning the whole extension.

So,

1. Is it possible to modify the language configuration inside VS code?
2. Or is it possible to modify the extension by creating another **minimal** extension, which only specifies items I want to add?

Comment: you can write a small (python) script that patches the files of the vhdl extension and restart VSC, you need to rerun the script each time the extension updates

Comment: @rioV8 Can I edit the source code of installed extensions? I thought that extensions from the MS marketplace are downloaded as binary.

Comment: Just go to the location where VSC extensions are installed and you will see that they are just copies of the repository, An vsix file is just a zip file of the source code with some meta data